# jqPlot - How to programmatically find under which jQuery UI tab plot exists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqplot

Please take a look at the following example:

http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/hiddenPlotsInTabs.html

In the first example, the hidden graphs are plotted by catching the "tabshow" event and finding which tab was selected:

```
$('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function (event, ui) {
    if (ui.index === 1 && plot1._drawCount === 0) {
        plot1.replot();
    } else if (ui.index === 2 && plot2._drawCount === 0) {
        plot2.replot();
    }
});
```

This works fine but if you added more tabs and moved your plots to other tabs, you'd have to manually update the hard coded "ui.index" values, which I'd like to avoid in my project.

Does anybody know a good way to programmatically find under which tab your plot exists?  I'd like to code in such a way that it doesn't matter how many tabs you have and where you place your plot.

Comment: +1 very interesting what you are actually going to do with it. Are you going to use Drag and Drop of some sort to me the charts around? If possible I would be interested in your final result of whatever you are coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to approach it in the following way:

1. Take the chart id you want to find from somewhere.
2. Use jQuery to select the chart.
3. Find its parent using `parent()` method --- this is the tab containing it.
4. Use `attr('id')` of the parent to get its id.

[This is how I show it in jsfiddle sample available here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/kU3jg/)

**EDIT**

From what I understand you want to get the index of selected tab, which is effectively ui.index. Since I couldn't find a ready method in the `jQuery UI`, this is how I achieved it (this code is also added to the previous jsfiddle sample):

```
    var tabIndex = -1;
    $("#tabs ul li").each(function(index){
        if('#'+tabId === $(this).find("a").attr('href')){
            tabIndex = index;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but how do you get the "ui.index" of the parent tab after doing parent()?  Here we're assuming the id of tabs are not named like tabs-1, tabs-2, tabs-3.  If they were it'd be easy to get the "ui.index" value.

Comment: Pleasure. Have fun coding. BTW can you elaborate what are you trying to make in the long run? :)

Comment: I'm using histograms to show frame based performance data.  I've got a few links under the histograms so user can switch between them.  The histograms live under one of my jQuery UI tabs, which are contained by a jQuery UI accordion.  If I have enough time I'd like to create a histogram version of this jqPlot demo: http://screencast.com/t/mHY5eUV99XaT

Comment: This looks very nice. Let me know if you manage to turn it into a plugin or something.