# How to force rendering a JSF composite component that use jQuery and jqPlot library

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, jqplot, composite

I use the excellent library Primefaces, but unfortunately I am forced to create my own component to customize it.

The problem is that the component is displayed well on the first tab but not the second.

How to force the display of the component during the loading of the tab?

Here the custom components **wm:dateLineChart** :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
    <h:panelGroup rendered="true">
        <div id="#{cc.id}" 
             style="height:208px;"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            var chartId = '<h:outputText value="#{cc.id}"/>';
            dateLineChart(chartId);

            function dateLineChart(id) {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery.jqplot (id, [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]], {
                        title: 'Plot With Options',
                        axesDefaults: {
                            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer
                        },
                        axes: {
                            xaxis: {
                                label: "X Axis",
                                pad: 0
                            },
                            yaxis: {
                                label: "Y Axis"
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </h:panelGroup>
</cc:implementation>
</html>
```

And here where i use it :

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true">  

    <p:tab id="homeView">  
        <wm:dateLineChart id="chartOnFirstTab" />
    </p:tab>  

    <p:tab id="otherView" >
        <wm:dateLineChart id="chartOnSecondTab" />
    </p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```

Thanking you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure your graph is plotted correctly you need to call the `replot()` method of an appropriate graph the very first time it is being shown (e.g. the graph containing tab is clicked).

This is how I do it for the `jQuery UI` tabs:

```
  $('#tabs').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.index === 1 && plot1._drawCount === 0) {
        plot1.replot();
      }
      else if (ui.index === 2 && plot2._drawCount === 0) {
        plot2.replot();
      }
  });
```

[The above code is presented here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/kU3jg/) The code sample is take [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10412837/613495). The approach I used there might be relevant to you if you need to find the tabs for your graphs.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works perfectly, the idea is to launch a replot when switching tabs. Since I use Primefaces I will post an adapted solution.

Answer (score 1):

An adapted solution with Primefaces. Hoping that it may serve others.

```
 <p:tabView id="tabView" dynamic="true" cache="true" onTabShow="refreshDateLineChart()" >
    //...
 </p:tabView>
```

The JS used :

```
 /**
  * The date line chart reference.
  */
 var DATE_LINE_CHART;

 /**
  * Draw the date line chart.
  * @param id : the div id
  */
 function dateLineChart(id) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        DATE_LINE_CHART = jQuery.jqplot (id, [[3,7,9,1,4,6,8,2,5]]);
    });
 }

 /**
  * Refresh the date line chart.
  */
 function refreshDateLineChart() {
    if (DATE_LINE_CHART != null && DATE_LINE_CHART._drawCount === 0) {
        DATE_LINE_CHART.replot();
    }
 }
```