# jqPlot Line Chart Not Drawing to Edge of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, layout, jqplot

I have a jqPlot line plot which is drawing beautifully, but I cannot get it to draw quite to the edge of the div it's contained in (which is critical to my application). I've tried every option for it that I can that has anything to do with removing margins, padding, etc., and there's still a fairly significant gap at the end. Also, I have confirmed for sure that the div itself reaches all the way to the right edge of the page. Below is my options code for the plot:

```
optionsObj = {
  stackSeries: true,
  axesDefaults: {
    show: false,
    showTicks: false,
    showTickMarks: false
  },
  axes: {
    grid: {
      drawBorder: false
    },
    xaxis: {
      pad: 0,
      tickOptions: {
        showGridline: false
      }
    },
    yaxis: {
      pad: 0,
      tickOptions: {
        showGridline: false
      }
    }
  },
  grid: {
    background: '#ffffff',
    borderColor: '#888888',
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    shadow: false
  },
  seriesDefaults: {
    lineWidth: 0.5,
    color: '#1A95ED',
    fill: true,
    markerOptions: {
      show: false
    }
  },
  series: seriesGroup,
  gridPadding: { top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }
};
```

A picture can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/js32405l6z16f2m/Capture.PNG

The slider is used to select a subset of this graph, which is graphed in a larger plot above. The problem is, because the graph is slightly scaled to the left and doesn't fill the same length as the slider, the selection is off. The left handle, for example, thinks it's just to the left of the second peak, and the right handle thinks it's just to the left of the fourth peak.

For those unfamiliar with jqPlot, there is a div declared:

```
<div id="overview" style="width:100%;height:200px"></div>
```

Which is drawn to by the function call:

```
$.jqplot('overview', eval('([' + sessionStorage.throughputData + '])'), optionsObj);
```

There is no CSS being applied to the chart other than the "style" attribute in the HTML declaration.

Comment: It would be very appreciated to see the problem for example in a runnable sample, e.g. at http://jsfiddle.net also a picture highlighting what you are after might help us to understand you better.

Comment: You could still paste a link place your image on some other site instead :)

Comment: I did my best to illustrate it. Unfortunately I couldn't post a picture, and I don't think this component of my page is standalone enough to use something like jsfiddle.net

Comment: Do not get me wrong I do appreciate the illustration very much. It is just to abstract for me to comprehend :)  So you would want the blue `thing'y` from the picture to reach to the end of the scroll, right? If so then what is the `CSS` you used for the chart?

Comment: Yeah. That way the slider and the graph would be lined up one-to-one, and the selection would be more meaningful.

Comment: It's okay if you can't figure it out, I really appreciate the effort :)

Comment: How do you set all the important components? I think it must be `CSS` related. Make a sample of, what I suspect, these three components: the slider, the chart and the container, and lets take it from there. BTW [are you aware of this](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/zoomProxy.html)  also @jpen did something similar, I guess, [under my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10412837/613495) he links to a screen cast, please see it.

Comment: That's really cool but I need to do this this way for mine. I have multiple charts that will use the same date/time selection. And what do you mean "how do I set them"?

Comment: I mean what is their `CSS` code. Please try to get the sample. It will also let you isolate the problem. Otherwise that is all from me :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that it's definitely not in the CSS. I know this because I can enable the chart's border (inside the chart library), and it is exactly the size I want it to be. But the line inside is still not quite reaching the edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed that the amount that the line was off would change depending on how many data points were in the chart. I did some experimenting, and eventually discovered that jqPlot, when deciding how many pixels each unit should get, tried to gravitate towards "nice" numbers of units for the total width of the graph. For example, when I had 1440 data points, the range of the graph itself would be 1600, and my data wouldn't go all the way to the end. When I had 2880 data points, the range of the graph would be 3000, and once again my data wouldn't fill it, but the amount by which it was off would change. I ended up manually setting the "min" and "max" values of the graph in units to match my data, and it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do with this one is to either set the min, max or set the ticks directly.

BTW the picture shows you are working with dates but in the options I see that you do not use the `DateAxisRenderer`, why is that so?

[I think you should check out my other answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233111/613495) Particularly if nothing will work you should consider setting the ticks directly. I know you are not showing them but anyway you can use them as the means of formatting the charts look. As I suspect you experience a similar behaviour as is observed in the first sample of the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some observations of my own:
I got it to work by setting xaxis/yaxis: pad to 1 **and not** 0.

I think pad is multiplied by the rage (min and max) to give the actual range in the chart. This will explain behavior noticed by @brandon.
Also make sure the range is a even or a multiple of the tick. I am not really sure, you have to experiment with this one.
With a set of 11 values I got spaces at either end, but a set of 10 values was flush to both ends.